# Backend server app which listens to multiple Server Sent Events and saves data to DB

Tags: node.js, server-sent-events

What would be the best tool/way to implement a server side application which will listen to multiple Server Sent Events(SSE) and do some action like saving values to a database on receiving the events. Also number of SSE listeners would change as new users gets registered. I am considering Node.js, please help me with your thoughts on implementing this as I am not from a server application development background.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution here would -if you are considering Nodejs- to use websockets. You can simply use `socket.io` and set it up on your own or use a PaaS to take of it for you, for example: http://pusher.com/.

Using websockets you can seamlessly communicate with the client (browser) and and send and receive information in real time. This can also be applied to any other device capable of doing HTTP connections.

To store the values you could use Redis, which is quite fast and should give you the simple and basic functionality you are looking for. If the actions need to be atomic, then you can build a simple worker process to write those values from Redis into your database, PostgreSQL for instance.